# Why won't this array display in accordance to its corresponding JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I'm trying to do is display an array (which repeats itself endlessly) in the browser. However, even though I can determine from the `console.logs` that the array is looping properly, what is ultimately being displayed in the browser isn't reflecting this and instead acting abnormally. [Here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rg8fcfej/). Below is the code, an explanation of what I believe is happening, and one of my failed attempts to resolve the issue.

## HTML

```
<div id="listings-container">
  <div class="listing" id="one"></div>
  <div class="listing" id="two"></div>
  <div class="listing" id="thr"></div>
  <div class="listing" id="fou"></div>
  <div class="listing" id="fiv"></div>
  <div class="listing" id="six"></div>
  <div class="listing" id="sev"></div>
  <div class="listing" id="eig"></div>
</div>
```

## JS

```
var listingClass      = document.getElementsByClassName('listing');
var listingsArray     = [];
var listingsContainer = document.getElementById('listings-container');
var moveOne           = window.innerHeight / 3;
var oneThird          = window.innerHeight / 3;

for (var i = 0; i < listingClass.length; i++) {
    listingsArray.push(listingClass[i]);
};

listingsContainer.addEventListener('scroll', test);
function test(){
    var first = listingsArray[0];
    if (listingsContainer.scrollTop >= moveOne) {
        moveOne += oneThird;
        listingsArray.shift();
        listingsArray.push(first);
        listingsContainer.removeChild(first);
        listingsContainer.appendChild(first);
        console.log(listingsArray);
    };
    console.log(listingsArray);
};
```

What's happening is that, as you scroll down, every other `listing` (i.e. `two`, `fou`, `six`, etc.) is being jumped over, so to speak, once the top of the element reaches the top of the browser. The reason this is happening, I believe, is because each `listing` is shifted upwards one spot, so I've tried adding the following code (which, for whatever reason, behaves exactly as it would without it).

## Additional CSS

```
 #listings-container:first-child {
     height: 33.33vh; /* same height as listings class */
 }
```

## Additional JS

```
var spacer = document.createElement('div');

listingsContainer.insertBefore(spacer, first);
```

I'm at a loss. Please help!

Comment: Unfortunately I can not clearly understand what you want to do. Do you maybe want some space between all the listing?

Comment: @Franco Sorry for that. I will try to explain better. I want to create a list that you can scroll forever, by removing each item as it moves off the top of the screen once you scroll passed it, and then reattaching that item to the bottom of the list. Does that make sense? I want to create an "endless" list without effecting the size of the scroll bar.

Comment: "*I believe each listing is shifted upwards one spot*" - well, yes, that happens when you remove the first child from the dom. The emptyness doesn't maintain the height of the spot. You can fix it either by creating more and more elements, or by changing the height/margin/padding at the top.

Comment: @Bergi Did you even bother to read the whole post? That is precisely what I tried doing, and it did not work for some reason...

Comment: @user2230470 Yes, the approach is good, but what I meant that you need to change the spacing *every time you remove an element*, i.e. increment the spacer height so that it matches the many elements that could be there. Static CSS doesn't solve that, and your code doesn't dynamically adapt the height of the `spacer` yet. Or did you put the "additional js" inside the `test` function?

Comment: @Bergi I understood what you meant, but I'm taking trying to address the problem one step at a time. If that code had actually worked, it wouldn't have jumped past the `#two`. For whatever reason, though, that code does not work.

Comment: Can you show the whole code that you're trying to use? It's not clear where you put the additional JS. Also, the `spacer` doesn't seem to have any styles applied to it.

Comment: @Bergi It doesn't matter too much where I put the variable, but I put `listingsContainer.insertBefore(spacer, first)` along with all of the other code in the `if else` statement. I have fixed the problem, however. `listingsContainer.scrollTop(-(oneThird))` wasn't working but `listingsContainer.scrollTop -= oneThird` works perfectly.

Comment: @Bergi NM about it being solved. I now remember that's why I gave up on using negative scrolling as a solution: it won't scroll upwards if somebody is using and holding the scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

You have the visual combination of 2 effects there:
- the regular scrolling
- the statements "listingsContainer.removeChild()" and "listingsContainer.appendChild()

As a result once the regular smooth scrolling has reached one third of the window height, the display jumps by an additional one third.

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish. You may need to scroll back by one third once you have removed and appended the first child.
If this is the case, use scrollBy() or scrollTo() to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I've already tried using `listingsContainer.scrollTop(-(oneThird))` but "If the number is a negative value, the number is set to `0`" (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp).

Comment: Add this as the last line of your if block:     `listingsContainer.scrollTop -= oneThird;`

Comment: omfg, you're a champ bro! not sure why i didn't think of trying that.

Comment: Glad that help. You still don't have infinite scrolling though. Of course, you will also have to handle the reverse scrolling.

Comment: yes, i noticed that. i haven't had time to really think about it yet, so i have no clue why that wouldn't be infinite?? :/ and good look for pointing out i'll have to handle the reverse. ohhhh, now i remember why i gave up on trying to use negative scrolling, because it won't scroll back if somebody scrolls using the scrollbar and is holding the scrollbar